# How do I remove a font's math metadata?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, metadata, equation-editor

I often write math documents in Word and recently I have installed a new font called "[NewComputerModern](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/newcomputermodern/otf)". It is supposed to be a normal font, but it is recognized by Word as a *math font* (i.e., if you insert an equation and go to "Conversions" menu, [it appears as a math font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c47qQ.png)), even if **it is not** a math font (there is another version of it that indeed has math support, but this is the one that is supposed not to have it).

The reason I don't want it to be recognized as a math font is simple: I want to write text with this font, call it font A, and write math equations with another font, say font B. But Word recognizes that font A is a math font (it shouldn't be), so instead of writing equations with font B, it automatically does it with font A (which hasn't math support, hence math equations look bad).

I believe a math font cannot be removed from Word's math font list, so I wanted to edit the OTF file itself with programs like *[Font Forge](https://fontforge.org/en-US/)* to remove math metadata, but I don't know what to tweak or delete. Which property of a font makes it recognized as a math font?
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the NewComputerModern font as an ordinary font,
by selecting it as the current font in the Home pane.
You are not obliged to use it only as a Math font.

You may set another font as the default Math font in the Conversions
dialog.

---

As you say that Word insists on using this font whatever your
setting, you may need to edit the OTF file.

I tried, for example, with the file `NewCMMath-Regular.otf`,
to edit it using the free online editor at
[Glyphr Studio](https://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/)
and gotten this interesting page:

---

[image]

---

This might be a way to create a new font that is not mathematical.
I haven't tried to go all the way through to see how it works,
but using the above options and saving the new font was already
pretty slow.

Comment: I tried, but the problem with Glyphr is doesn't export the font weights the right way: Word only uses the Regular version of it, and applies faux bold and italics even if the variants are present. Of course, I export them with the same name (and different styles).
If I export them with the name "NCM", then I have to manually write "NCMItalic" or "NCMBold" on the Word homepage to make it work, but it won't work with "B" and "I" buttons. Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean that also converting the bold and italics versions with this site does not result in all the converted fonts to be recognized as one font family?

Comment: It _is_ recognized as one font family, even if I go to the fonts system folder they are in the same family. In fact, Word shows only one of the 4 variants, and even if I press the `B` or `I` buttons, it will create fake italics and bold, instead of using the dedicated font weights.